Why is action potential (electric impulse in nervous system) transferred in series only?
Action potential is initiated when sodium-channels (conductors, voltage gated resistors) are opened, allowing sodium ions them to flow across the cell membrane (capacitor).
Flow of sodium ions (current) across the membrane doesn't happen at the same time everywhere along the axon. Flow is initiated at the one end of the axon and is transmitted in series along the axon length. This serial transmission is called electric impulse.
My question is: Why can't flow of sodium-ions happen simultaneously everywhere along the axon length? What is stopping this process?
Sodium channels are voltage gated and hence should be opened everywhere along the axon length if the potential difference is appropriate and the same everywhere across the membrane.

This might help - Neuron action potential - physiology


Sodium channels are voltage gated and hence should be opened everywhere along the axon length if the potential difference is appropriate and the same everywhere across the membrane.

The potential difference isn't the same across the plasma membrane during this process. There is local depolarization that propagates down the cell. That's what the action potential is: a propagating depolarization followed by repolarization.
